# asynchronous callback exception while inserting object to collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to insert the object in  FamilyData  and same object in UserData in callback function of FamilyData.But here,I am able to insert an object to FamilyData but in callback function object I am getting is null.And it is causing asynchronous callback exception.In console ,I am getting upto "user id present" with stringified object but after that "FamilyId" is not printing.There it is showing null object.
The code I have attached below:

```
             `
             registerNewUser': function (obj) {               
             let result=null;
             result = {};
             let UserData1;
                try {
             let userId;
            let messageArray;
            let FamilyEmail;
            let FamilyId1;
          messageArray = Meteor.Validation.Registration(obj);
         if (messageArray.length > 0) {
             let msg = Meteor.Utility.appendMessages(messageArray);
            result.Success = false;
            result.Message = msg;
            } else {

           result.Success = true;
           result.Message = 'User added successfully';
            if (!obj.check_familymember) {
                    userId = Accounts.createUser({
                    email: obj.email,
                    password: obj.pwd
                });
                if (userId != undefined) {
             console.log("user id present",JSON.stringify(obj));
                    FamilyData.insert({
                        FamilyName: obj.FamilyName,
                        Address: obj.Address,
                        CreatedBy: obj.firstname,
                        Latitude: obj.latitude,
                        Longitude: obj.longitude
                    }, function (err, FamilyId) {

            console.log("FamilyId",JSON.stringify(obj));
                        UserData.insert({
                            FirstName: obj.firstname,
                            LastName: obj.lastname,
                            Gender: obj.genderval,
                            DateOfBirth: obj.dob,
                            Email: obj.email,
                            Password: obj.pwd,
                            FamilyId: FamilyId,
                            UserId: userId,
                        });
                        if(err){
                            // throw err;
                            result.Message=err;
                            console.log("error is",err);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("user created");

                } else {
                    result.Success = false;
                    result.Message = 'Unable to create user ';
                }
            } else {

                 FamilyEmail = obj.FamilyEmailId;
                    UserData1 = UserData.findOne({
                    Email: FamilyEmail
                });
                if (UserData1 == null) {
                    result.Success = false;
                    result.Message = 'FamilyId does not exist..';
                } else {
                     FamilyId1 = UserData1.FamilyId;
                     userId = Accounts.createUser({
                        email: obj.email,
                        password: obj.pwd
                    });
                    if (userId != undefined) {
                        UserData.insert({
                            FirstName: obj.firstname,
                            LastName: obj.lastname,
                            Gender: obj.genderval,
                            DateOfBirth: obj.dob,
                            Email: obj.email,
                            Password: obj.pwd,
                            FamilyId: FamilyId1,
                            UserId: userId
                        });
                    } else {
                        result.Success = false;
                        result.Message = 'Unable to create user ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logError(e);
        result.Success = false;
        result.Message = e.message;
    }
     `
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses fibers to run asynchronous code

so you don't havee to use callback in db operations

try the following

```
    let familyId = FamilyData.insert({
                       FamilyName: obj.FamilyName,
                       Address: obj.Address,
                       CreatedBy: obj.firstname,
                       Latitude: obj.latitude,
                       Longitude: obj.longitude
                   });
```

Comment: I have to pass the  id which is created on Family Data collection to UserData collection immediately as FamilyId